# When i format code , mutiple line becomes one line

Tags: visual-studio-code

I have code below

```
console.log(e)
console.log(e.target.value)
this.update({
  name: e.target.value
})
```

when i format the code , it become as

```
console.log(e)console.log(e.target.value)this.update({name: e.target.value})
```

this cause errors,  how i can change the behave? in my another computer, format doesn't behave like this, i tried copy my format setting to this computer but doesn't work, how can i fix it?

Comment: Is it possible to insert semicolons after each line? :D It is confusing both for computers and people to read code without any ; separating the lines, expext for python.

Comment: @StephanT.  : )   I learned from an article by Evan You, creator of Vue.js  about the `ASI`(automatic semicolon insertion) mechanism, So now I used to not write semicolons, and in my another computer when i format  it doesn't break the lines. Thanks for your comment!

Comment: Which version of Visual Studio are you using on your machine?

Comment: Both the newest version

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't hesitate to use semicolons in your code:

```
console.log(e);
console.log(e.target.value);
this.update({
   name: e.target.value
});
```

The issue might just be visual studio not knowing how to format asi (the semicolons are in fact missing, until they are added by the compiler). My vs tells me that the semicolons are missing, it, doesn't format them wrong, but still, it's not that pretty and causes you problems, so why bother and delete them in the first place :D